# My AngularJS expressions don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression

I have recently taken up learning AngularJS, but I ran into a bit of a problem. I tried to use the code language in WebMatrix 3, and I got the directives working, but the expressions don't show up well in the webpage. In the code I type:

```
<p>{{ title }}</p>
```

Then in the webpage it will show: {{ title }} instead of the title I programmed.

Here is the rest of my code.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-app="myApp">

<div data-ng-controller="MainController">
<p>{{ title }}</p>
{{ 5 + 5 }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

MainController.js:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title = 'Top Sellers in Books';
} ]);
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

So does anyone know why the expressions won't show my data? I tried it with things like {{ 5 + 5 }} and it still didn't work.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is the script tag to include your MainController.js and app.js files in the html doc? Try adding that.

Comment: Your code is correct, just add the <script> tag declaring your MainController.js, here's a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/QvbbjeYubpXYa3ZtXQsN?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment, you have obviously not included a `script` tag to reference the files containing your app module initialization and controller code, and that is why your expressions don't work.

You should include that script below the angular script in your head section.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fileContainingYourControllerScript.js"></script>
</head>
```

**refactoring bonus**: Once you get it working, do some refactoring and move all your scripts out of the header and put them in the bottom of your HTML, before the ending tag of your HTML doc. It will improve page-load performance. You can also think about using **Bower** to manage your dependencies (Angular etc).

Comment: For some odd reason, that still doesn't fix the problem. It just does the same annoying thing. Any ideas?

Comment: The plunker by Fourat in the comments shows how to include the additional script correctly. Check it out.